# MySQL Error, specifically an If Exist statement

Tags: mysql

I tried using from mySQL the If Exists statement but i got an error from mysql saying there's a #1064 syntax error, but i really couldn't find it. There are my codes:

```
If EXISTS (select * from points where username= 'john')
update points set points = "4" where username='john'
ELSE
insert into points (username, points) values ('john', 5);
```

Comment: What is the primary key of the `points` table?  If you could explain what your logic is, you might not need to use an upsert here.

Comment: Hi! The primary key is "username"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to achieve your logic would be to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` while doing your `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO points (username, points)
VALUES ('john', 5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points=4
```

This query will insert `('john', 5')` into your table, but if the primary key username `john` already exists, then it will points to 4.

Comment: Seriously...who is downvoting this answer without leaving any feedback whatsoever?  What does this accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your statement. You are missing "THEN" keyword after EXISTS and "END IF" at the end, and also missing a semicolon on UPDATE statement. If you still want to go with this statement, it should be like this:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from points where username= 'john') THEN
    UPDATE points set points = "4" where username = 'john';
ELSE
    INSERT into points (username, points) values ('john', 5);
END IF;
```

Please take a note that this statement can be only used in routine such as Stored Procedure or Stored Function and not in normal SQL.

On the other hand, what @TimBiegeleisen said in his answer is a more efficient way to go.